# default radio input checked attribute not working with can-value

Tags: radio-button, canjs, livebindings

`Using can 2.2` : I'm having trouble getting a radio input field to be checked by default when also using the `can-value` attribute.

**The relevant part of the stache template looks like this:**

```
<input type="radio" name="visibility" value="corporate" can-value="reportData.visibility" checked="checked"/>
```

**The relevant part of my viewModel looks like this:**

```
can.Map.extend({
    reportData = {
        visibility: 'corporate',    
    }
});
```

I want the input value to be live-bound to my view model.  According to the [can 2.2 docs](http://canjs.com/2.2/docs/can.view.bindings.can-value.html), I can use the can-value attribute on an input to reference a property on my view model and keep it in sync with the value of the input's value.  My problem is the `checked="checked"` doesn't result in the input being checked by default, though the value on the input item (`corporate`) is being correctly live-bound.  If I remove the `can-value` attribute, the check appears by default.  How can I get both live-binding and a checked input by default with the help of `can-value`?

Comment: Can you try can 2.3 - a lot of improvements were made in that release - and most of the regressions have been fixed. If you can't upgrade, I will need you to create a fiddle showing the error- I can create a starter fiddle for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm bound to canjs 2.2. However I was able to get the checked feature to work by surrounding the checked attribute in a conditional helper, i.e. {{#is reportData.visibility 'corporate'}}checked{{/is}} . Not ideal, but it works.